# Insert "one" blank row every "variable" number of rows - including LOOP?

Tags: vba

can anyone advise how can I turn  `RowIncrement = 2` into a "loop" that goes and pick ups the values from a column based on the other sheet? So, if the first value in the column is 1 then `RowIncrement = 1`, then it goes to the next value in that column, which may be e.g. 6 and then `RowIncrement = 6` and so on.

```
Sub EmptyRowEveryX()

Dim NumRowsToInsert As Long
Dim RowIncrement As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastEvenlyDivisibleRow
Dim i As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim HowMany As Integer

NumRowsToInsert = 1


RowIncrement = 2

Set ws = ActiveSheet

For n = LastRow To 1 Step -1

HowMany = Range("BM" & z)

If (HowMany > 1) Then

Rows(z & ":" & HowMany).Insert Shift:=xlDown

End If

With ws
    LastRow = .Range("AZ" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = Int(LastRow / RowIncrement) * RowIncrement
    If LastEvenlyDivisibleRow = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If




    For i = LastEvenlyDivisibleRow To 1 Step -RowIncrement
        .Range(i & ":" & i + (NumRowsToInsert - 1)).Insert xlShiftDown
    Next i



End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, share what you have done so far and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: `enters only 1 row every x number of cells that are in cells in col BM`. This isn't clear - can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub OneEmptyRow()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Range("AZ1", Range("AZ" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        .Subtotal GroupBy:=1, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(1), _
            Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
        .Offset(, -1).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*total*"
        .Offset(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
        .AutoFilter
        .Offset(, -1).EntireColumn.Delete
        .EntireColumn.RemoveSubtotal
    End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```